# Where can I find Maven POM for building Tomcat from source?

Tags: tomcat, maven, open-source

I have downloaded Apache Tomcat sources and built them with Ant script provided. I want to use Maven instead of Ant because it is much more convinient and familiar to me. Where can I find Maven POM file for building Apache Tomcat from sources?

Comment: There is no `pom.xml` available for the Tomcat sources. There is nothing in the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html) that mentions anything about maven in the build process. Where have you heard that this is an option?

Comment: Maba, I just guess that someone before me was trying to build Tomcat from source and wanted to switch to Maven from Ant.

Comment: I prefer Maven over Ant any day of the week but that doesn't make it a viable option all the time. To switch from Ant to Maven quite a lot of work has to be done and obviously it has not been done.

Comment: Well, probably its just writing correct POM with the dependencies. Tomcat is so many years old that I thought it was done by someone.. at least for some old version..

Comment: Writing correct POM - yes. But then you will have to maintain two different build systems so that their dependencies do not diverge.

Comment: Maintain Ants? Why? I dont need it, and even more - I am not going to update my project from repository. All I want is a working Tomcat Maven build, not that much actually :)

Comment: It can be much more than just writing a pom . . . I promise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official Maven build process for any version of Tomcat. The topic has been discussed several times amongst the community and the developers and none of the developers feel compelled to change switch the Tomcat build process from Ant to Maven. If someone can provide compelling reasons to switch (and not just "because Maven is better!"), they may reconsider.